# Get number of available executors

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm spinning up an EMR 5.4.0 cluster with Spark installed.  I have a job for which performance really degrades if it's scheduled on executors which aren't available (eg on a cluster w/ 2 m3.xlarge core nodes there are about 16 executors available).

Is there any way for my app to discover this number?  I can discover the hosts by doing this:
`sc.range(1,100,1,100).pipe("hostname").distinct().count()`, but I'm hoping there's a better way of getting an understanding of the cluster that Spark is running on.

Comment: doesn't EMR offer a console where you can see the available executors?

Comment: I want this programmatically so I can launch the job with the right amount of parallelism.